# Change navigation direction react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a component that navigates to the Home page using "navigation.navigate('Home');", but the home screen always comes in from the right. How do I make the home screen come in from the left?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using react-navigation and the default stack navigator, you can specify `gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted'` on the entire navigator (to have all screens follow this behaviour) or on the screen you want (so that only this screen slides in from the left:

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted'}}>
// or:
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{gestureDirection: 'horizontal-inverted'}}>
```

You can read more about this option, and animations in general in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animation-related-options.

#### Update (native-stack)

When using native-stack navigator, customisation options are limited.

Note that this solution will only work for certain cases, as it depends on the screen hierarchy at the time of navigation.

Essentially, you might use `replace` instead of `navigate` or `push` and specify `pop` as the animation your Home Screen will use for `replace` transitions:

```js
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{animationTypeForReplace: "pop"}} />
```

You can find a working example snack here: https://snack.expo.dev/@mlisik/stack-overflow---pop-animation (note that to see the result you will need to run it on device)

Comment: Right now the only gesture direction that is allowed is "horizontal". Is there some other way to flip the direction?

Comment: What do you mean by allowed?

Comment: The only gestureDirections that I have the option of using are "horizontal" and "vertical". Inverted is not an option somehow

Comment: Ah, you are using the native stack navigator. My bad, I assumed it's the default one. In that case options are slightly limited, but I'll update my answer with an alternative that I used in the past.